# Merge API context with session

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

I have the following problem:
I have a landing page which is outside of shopware context. I have add to cart buttons and want to add products to a cart.

What I can do and works:

- create api context
- create cart
- add product

What doesn't work yet - interaction with the shop:

- Use the cart which already exists to start with
- Continue with the cart which we created and use the normal checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to get the context from the session (this depends on the same php context … cookies, same donain, etc.). I hacked it this way:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

function generateRandomString()
{
    $characters = implode('', range('a', 'z')) . implode('', range('A', 'Z')) . implode('', range(0, 9));
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[random_int(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    return $randomString;
}

session_name('session-');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['sw-context-token'])) {
    $_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['sw-context-token'] = generateRandomString();
}
?>


<script>
   const context = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['sw-context-token'], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)?>;
</script>
```

This `context` is then used in the API calls. And it works like a charm.

Comment: Okay so you have your landing page on the same domain? Or how were you able to get the session cookie?